# Having a webapp running into a VSCode's WebView

Tags: web-applications, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to write a web application that will run in the browser but I also want the app accessible directly within VS Code. My question is how to organize that so I don't have to duplicate the source code of the webapp into the code of the VS Code extension?

Comment: Have you already had a look at this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview

Comment: Did ChatterOne's example work? Seems like an interesting use case